# How to backup 100 mysql databases at once in localhost?

Tags: mysql, xampp, localhost

I have 100 databases in my localhost. I want to backup all of them at once. I want a quick method to do this. Is there anyway to backup all databases at once?

Comment: maybe this tool helps? http://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this url http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_all-databases. this should help

**How to use?**

```
shell> mysqldump [options] --all-databases
```

Answer (score 3):

You can dump multiple databases at once with [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html).

With the following command you can dump several databases at once.

```
mysqldump --databases db1 db2 db3 > db_backup.sql
```

Or if you want to dump all databases:

```
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > db_backup.sql
```

Comment: Where are the files stored after exportation? I just tried the second step and I got no warning or notification whatsoever.

Comment: The output is stored in the db_backup.sql file

Answer (score 1):

Its as simple as backing up one single database.
Just do as follows

1. Go to http://localhost/phpmyadmin
2. Navigate to Export tab
3. In Export method, choose '*Custom - display all possible options*' and select the database you want to export if not all.
4. Scroll below and in **Object creation options** Make sure you select

   - Add CREATE DATABASE / USE statement
   - Add DROP TABLE / VIEW / PROCEDURE / FUNCTION / EVENT / TRIGGER statement
5. Click Go and Let all you table be saved in default download folder or select it manually.
6. Default File name would be *127_0_0_1.sql* Make sure you open this file with text editor and verify if sql command is correct, at least for first database and first table.
   it should be backed up now.
   If having any Problem in doing so, please leave comment below to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqldump` with the `--all-databases` option. See 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_all-databases

Answer (score 0):

You could use *mysqldump* to create a backup of your mysql databases.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mysqldump -uusername -ppassword --all-databases > all_dbs.sql
```

Hope this helps!